# Installing SSL certificate for IBM Websphere - HTTPServer

Tags: ssl, websphere, ssl-certificate, httpserver

The SSL certificate we had for our website expired 2 days ago and I've been trying to install the new certificate on our IBM Websphere HTTPServer. I've referenced the [following documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/cihs_certmgmt.html) and accordingly, I've completed the following steps:

- Generated a new CSR for the existing CMS keystore (plugin-key.kdb)
- Received the signed SSL certificate and added it to plugin-key.kdb
- Added the signer's root and intermediate certificate to plugin-key.kdb
- When I run the command to list the certificates in the keystore, I am able to see the SSL certificate.

However, when I try to access https://domain.com I get ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH in Chrome. I also tried performing an SSL check on the site using SSL checker but the checker surprisingly says, "no SSL certificates were found on domain.com"

I have recycled Websphere - done a hard and a soft reboot but the certificate just doesn't show up or get picked up by the browser.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You created the certificate in the wrong keystore. The `plugin-key.kdb` is keystore for WebSphere plugin, it is used in communication between plugin and WebSphere Application Server.

You need to change the keystore which is used by IHS (the http server). 
In the `httpd.conf` file, look for following entry `KeyFile "c:/Program Files/IBM HTTP Server/key.kdb"` , that will be the keystore used by IHS.

You will need to export the certificate with private keys from plugin store and add it as personal certificate to the IHS keystore.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I could be wrong, but I don't think I agree with your take as given below is the SSL configuration I have in my `httpd.conf` file: `LoadModule ibm_ssl_module modules/mod_ibm_ssl.so
Listen 443
<VirtualHost 50.22.217.43:443>
SSLEnable
</VirtualHost>
KeyFile "/opt/IBM/WebServer/Plugins/config/webserver1/plugin-key.kdb"
SSLDisable
# End of example SSL configuration` I couldn't find any other `KeyFile` directive in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: @TejasTotade In that case you are correct and plugin-key is used for IHS. You can check plugin-cfg.xml file to see keystore for plugin. I wrote that as usually separate keystores are created for IHS and plugin.

Comment: @TejasTotade Which IHS version are you running? Try accessing with different browser, also check [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=a4d8a74c-3d46-408f-be25-84ca9505bd1f), after adding new certificate, you may need to open the keystore and change the default certificate.

Comment: I am running IBM WAS 8.5 and IHS - 2.2.15 (Apache). I followed the thread you'd linked to and set the default certificate. However, now I am getting a ERR_SSL_DECRYPT_ERROR_ALERT error in Chrome :(

Comment: @TejasTotade Where do you see that error, in http server logs? Did you try different browser e.g. Firefox?

Comment: I am getting ssl_error_decrypt_error_alert in Firefox. Really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I even tried to switch to using the admin GUI and followed the instructions given here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7q7gXZg1DbA The only change was in the SSL error message.

Answer (score 0):

The key file does sound strange. Usually that is for communication between plugin and application server. Make sure you have the right intermediaries selected in the kdb file. Did your CA give you any intermediary keys? Those may be needed. Sometimes the one that comes with Ikeyman are not sufficient. Also make sure you are terminating SSL at the IHS server and not somewhere else like a Netscaler or F5. Also check that the Deployment manager is not overwriting the changed plugin file back to the original one, since you are manually changing this file that is usually generated and propagated by the dmgr.